# Como obtengo la direccion URL de una imagen guardada en FirebaseStorage?

Tags: android-studio, firebase, kotlin, database-android

Subi una imagen a firebase storage y guarde su referencia en la base de datos pero al momento de mostrar la url de la imagen el vinculo que me muestra la base de datos es algo asi:
"com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@3e0a650"

Necesito un url valido para luego poder implementar un RecyclerView.

Este es mi codigo?

```
 private fun saveProductInfoToDatabase()
{

    val descripcion = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.product_description).text.toString()
    val pName = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.product_name).text.toString()

    val precio = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.product_price).text.toString()

    val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    val filePath: StorageReference = productImageRef!!.child(imageUri!!.lastPathSegment +
            productRandomKey + ".jpg")
    val downloadImageUrl = filePath.downloadUrl.toString()
    
    val categoryName = intent.extras?.get("categoria").toString()

    val currentDate = SimpleDateFormat("dd MM, yyyy")

    val saveCurrentDate = currentDate.format(calendar.time)

    val currentTime = SimpleDateFormat(" HH:mm:ss")
    val saveCurrentTime = currentTime.format(calendar.time)
    val productRandomKey = saveCurrentDate + saveCurrentTime
    val productMap= HashMap<String, Any>()
    productMap.put("pid", productRandomKey)
    productMap.put("fecha", saveCurrentDate)
    productMap.put("hora", saveCurrentTime)
    productMap.put("descripcion", descripcion)
    productMap.put("precio", precio)
    productMap.put("imagen", downloadImageUrl)
    productMap.put("categoria", categoryName)
    productMap.put("Nombre", pName)

    productRef.child(pName).updateChildren(productMap)

        .addOnCompleteListener()
        {
            if (it.isSuccessful)
            {
                val intent = Intent(this, AdminCategoryActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)

                Toast.makeText(this, "Producto agregado satisfactoriamente", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

            }
            else
            {
                val message = it.exception.toString()
                Toast.makeText(this, "Error: $message" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }

        }
}
```

La referencia que obtengo de la imagen es una url invalida

[image: la referencia que obtengo en Firebase Realtime Database es algo asi:]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que debes hacer es subir esa imagen al servidor de Firebase Storage, el servidor una vez que subio el archivo en la dirección que proporcionas genera una url para ese archivo, en este caso siguiendo la [documentacion](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files?hl=es)

Podemos hacer lo siguiente

```
var uploadTask:UploadTask
    val filePath: StorageReference = productImageRef!!.child(imageUri!!.lastPathSegment +
                productRandomKey + ".jpg")

val ref = filePath.child("imagenes")
    
   uploadTask = ref.putFile(tu_imagen_en_archivo)
    
    val urlTask = uploadTask.continueWithTask { task ->
        if (!task.isSuccessful) {
            task.exception?.let {
                throw it
            }
        }
        ref.downloadUrl
    }.addOnCompleteListener { task ->
        if (task.isSuccessful) {
            val downloadUri = task.result  //Obten la url de tu imagen, acá es donde vas a guardar esta url para hacer luego el updateChildren, ya que esta es la url final de tu imagen que debes enviar a Firebase
        } else {
            // Maneja el error
            // ...
        }
    }
```

Comment: Resuelto! muchas gracias!